# How to sort IP addresses with port number?

Tags: python, sorting, ip

I am creating my own reporting tool, and I am trying to figure out how to sort IP address with port number.

How do I sort an IP address with port number such that I sort the IP address first and then through port number. I am able to sort IP address just fine, but when combining with port numbers, it becomes difficult.

```
a = ['192.168.0.3 (443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.176 (443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.40 (443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.15 (8443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.16 (8443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.12 (443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.9 (3389/tcp)|', '192.168.0.15 (443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.16 (443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.3 (3389/tcp)|', '192.168.0.14 (443/tcp)|']

print(a.sort(key=lambda s: map(int, s.split('.')))) #this works fine with just IP address not with the current format of (xxx/tcp). The pipe is for delimiters so please ignore.
```

I would like to get the output sorted by IP address first, and then for each IP to sort via port number. So for example, the first few results would be:

```
a= ['192.168.0.3 (443/tcp)|', '192.168.0.3 (3389/tcp)|', 192.168.0.9 (3389/tcp)|, ...']
```

Comment: Shouldn't `'192.168.0.9 (3389/tcp)|'` be the 3rd in the desired output?

Comment: @Chris corrected, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `re.findall`:

```
import re

def get_ip_port(x):
    *ips, port = map(int, re.findall('\d+', x))
    return ips, port

sorted(a, key=get_ip_port)
```

Output:

```
['192.168.0.3 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.3 (3389/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.9 (3389/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.12 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.14 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.15 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.15 (8443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.16 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.16 (8443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.40 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.176 (443/tcp)|']
```

Explanation:

- `map(int, re.findall('\d+', x))`: finds all digits and make them `int`
- `*ips, port`: unpacks the above `int`s and repack into all but last one (`*ips`) and last one (`port`)
- `sorted(a, key=get_ip_port)`: as `get_ip_port` returns two keys (`ips`,`port`), `sorted` sorts the `a` first by `ips` and then `port`, just as desired.

Comment: This is great, would you be able to explain/comment a little on what the steps do? Thank you.

Comment: @Anderson Updated. Please let me know if anything stays unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort with multiple criteria(with `map(int,e[0].split('.'))`as criteria 1 and `int(e[1].lstrip('(').split('/')[0])` as criteria2) as shown below,

```
>>> a
['192.168.0.3 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.176 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.40 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.15 (8443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.16 (8443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.12 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.9 (3389/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.15 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.16 (443/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.3 (3389/tcp)|',
 '192.168.0.14 (443/tcp)|']
>>> [i.split() for i in a]
[['192.168.0.3', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.176', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.40', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.15', '(8443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.16', '(8443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.12', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.9', '(3389/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.15', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.16', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.3', '(3389/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.14', '(443/tcp)|']]

>>> sorted([i.split() for i in a],key=lambda e: (map(int,e[0].split('.')),int(e[1].strip('(').split('/')[0])))
[['192.168.0.3', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.3', '(3389/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.9', '(3389/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.12', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.14', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.15', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.15', '(8443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.16', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.16', '(8443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.40', '(443/tcp)|'],
 ['192.168.0.176', '(443/tcp)|']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in just one line using `sorted` like so:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x:x.split(' ')[0])
```