# Sort a list of tuples by ip address

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples with ip addresses as the first element

```
tuple_list = [
    ('192.168.0.15', 33, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.22', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.1', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.2', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.8', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.11', 34, 60)
]
```

and I want to sort it by the ip address, however it prints like this:

```
print(sorted(tuple_list))

[
    ('192.168.0.1', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.11', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.15', 33, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.2', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.22', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.8', 34, 60)
]
```

When instead I want it like this:

```
[
    ('192.168.0.1', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.2', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.8', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.11', 34, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.15', 33, 60), 
    ('192.168.0.22', 34, 60)
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort IP addresses stored in dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545023/how-to-sort-ip-addresses-stored-in-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: do you want the other elements to be considered in the sort? So if ip addresses were the same, should the sort then look to the second and then third elements to decide order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort IP addresses with port number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372527/how-to-sort-ip-addresses-with-port-number)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print(sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda x:int(x[0].split('.')[-1])))
```

If your IPs have multiple difference network segment such as [('192.168.0.1'), ('192.168.1.1'), ('192.168.2.254')], use:

```py
print(sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda ip_tuple:
    int(''.join(map(lambda ip_segment:
        bin(int(ip_segment))[2:], ip_tuple[0].split('.'))))))
```

Comment: @shaikmoeed Yes, but this situation is not included in question description.

Comment: It's a sample data, dupe link has the right logic to solve OP issue.

Comment: @shaikmoeed You are right. I would add an interesting method for such issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ipaddress` module to store the ip addresses instead of strings. This way they are comparable to each other then sort using `operator.itemgetter`. This seems to me to be the most efficient and no need for a lambda expression to sort.

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address
from operator  import itemgetter

tuple_list = [(IPv4Address('192.168.0.15'), 33, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.22'), 34, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.1'), 34, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.2'),34, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.8'), 34, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.11'), 34, 60)]

print(sorted(tuple_list, key=itemgetter(0)))
#[(IPv4Address('192.168.0.1'), 34, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.2'), 34, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.8'), 34, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.11'), 34, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.15'), 33, 60), (IPv4Address('192.168.0.22'), 34, 60)]
```

I just used this simple comprehension to make the strings to `IPv4Address`.

```
[(IPv4Address(x), y, z) for x, y, z in tuple_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the python interpreter to sort the ip addressed considering them as numbers, hence you need to split it and convert the ip address into numbers. `2 < 11` but `'2' > '11'`.

Consider the first element of each tuple (the ip address), split it at every `.`, convert the split up list of strings to a list of ints using map. Finally convert the map object (generator) to a tuple. Use this tuple of ints as the key to sort the entire list.

```py
from pprint import pprint

sorted_tuples = sorted(
    tuple_list, 
    key=lambda t: tuple(map(int, t[0].split('.')))
)

pprint(sorted_tuples)
```

Output:

```
[('192.168.0.1', 34, 60),
 ('192.168.0.2', 34, 60),
 ('192.168.0.8', 34, 60),
 ('192.168.0.11', 34, 60),
 ('192.168.0.15', 33, 60),
 ('192.168.0.22', 34, 60)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def getkey(item):
    lst = item.split('.')
    num = ((int(lst[0])*1000 + int(lst[1]))*1000 + int(lst[2]))*1000 + int(lst[3])
    return(num)

print(sorted(tuple_list, key=getkey))
```